# Parse nodeJs Date.toString() output as time in go

Tags: javascript, node.js, go

I have a go service which receives data from an external service.

The data looks as follows (json)-

```json
{
  "firstName": "XYZ",
  "lastName": "ABC",
  "createdAtTimestamp": "Mon Nov 21 2022 17:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
}
```

Note that `createdAtTimestamp` is the output in format of nodeJS `new Date().toString()` which does not have any particular RFC format specified.

How do I parse `createdAtTimestamp` to `time` in go ?

I tried this but it is failing-

```golang
data, _ := time.Parse(time.RFC1123, "Mon Nov 21 2022 17:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)")
    fmt.Println(data.Format(time.RFC3339))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below `Layout` to parse your date:

```
"Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 MST-0700"
```

In the lines of:

```
date := "Mon Nov 21 2022 17:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
data, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 MST-0700", strings.Split(date, " (")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You see time.RFC1123 in the docs https://pkg.go.dev/time, it does not actually match your format. https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants.

If you know the format of the `createdAtTimestamp` then first you have to define a layout with the format.

[solution at go.dev](https://go.dev/play/p/i9EIQjEKvog)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // The date and time string you want to parse
    createdAtTimestamp := "Mon Nov 21 2022 17:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

    // The format of the date and time string
    layout := "Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 MST-0700 (India Standard Time)"

    // Parse the date and time string
    parsedTime, err := time.Parse(layout, createdAtTimestamp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Print the parsed time in RFC3339 format
    fmt.Println(parsedTime.Format(time.RFC3339))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to strip off `(India Standard Time)` (unless you know it will be the same each time), but you can do

https://go.dev/play/p/rWqO9W3laM2

```
str := "Mon Nov 21 2022 17:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
data, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 MST-0700", str[:strings.Index(str, " (")])
fmt.Println(data.Format(time.RFC3339), err)
```

or, if it will always have `(India Standard Time)`, you could do:

```
str := "Mon Nov 21 2022 17:01:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
data, err := time.Parse("Mon Jan 02 2006 15:04:05 MST-0700 (India Standard Time)", str)
fmt.Println(data.Format(time.RFC3339), err)
```